# Java ClassNotFoundException in Command Prompt Even Though it Compiles

Tags: java, terminal, command, classnotfoundexception, prompt

I'm trying to run a very simple program using Java and the Command Prompt terminal. I can compile programs successfully because the "insertFileName".class files are appearing in the correct folder after I use the javac command, and I think my path for java is ok, because when I use the "java -version" command, I get the version info. But if I compile, say, Test.java, it will compile, Test.java will appear in the folder, and when I try the command

> java Test

I get an ClassNotFoundException error.

//The Test.java file

```
public class Test   {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Arggh!!");
    }
}
```

//And this is what goes into the terminal

```
C:\Users\Colin N\Documents\JAVAPROGRAMS>javac Test.java

C:\Users\Colin N\Documents\JAVAPROGRAMS>java Test
Error: Could not find or load main class Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
```

Comment: The current working directory is not in your classpath.  Use `java -classpath . Test` to run your program (from inside the build directory).

Comment: It worked!! Thank you for your help.